# Is the ordering of a sufficient statistic meaningful (soft question, maybe)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have distribution with a vector of parameters, and a random sample of size n from said distribution. Is the writing order of a sufficient statistic meaningful?

For a normal distribution, we often say that $(\bar{X},S^2)$ is a sufficient statistic for
$(\mu,\sigma^2)$. The reason for writing it this way (probably) is because when one of these parameters is known, a sufficient statistic for $\mu$ is $\bar{X}$ and for $\sigma^2$ is $S^2$. However, would it be valid to say that $(S^2,\bar{X})$ is a sufficient statistic for $(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

Or for example, would it be valid to say $(X_{(2)},X_{(1)},X_{(3)},...,X_{(n)})$ (subscript denotes order statistic) is a sufficient statistic for $(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Hint: the function $(x,y)\to(y,x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a (smooth) one-to-one correspondence.  Now apply the definition of sufficient statistic.

Comment: @whuber, thank you! That's sort of my point (these statistics correspond to the same partitioning of the sample space). But is there a desired convention for such a listing?

Comment: It's natural to list a statistic based on a lower moment, such as $\bar X,$ before a statistic based on a higher moment, such as $S^2,$ so you most often see the pair in that order.  But there's no need for a convention, because both ordered pairs $(\bar X, S^2)$ and $(S^2,\bar X)$ are perfectly clear.

Comment: @whuber, thank you!!